# What is the best way to add ratio lines to plot in ggplot2?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, scatter-plot

I have constructed the follow scatter plot in ggplot2:

```
q<-ggplot(data,aes(x=prot..,y=carb..,group=factor(early.or.late),color=factor(early.or.late))+geom_point(),size=4)+scale_color_manual(values=c("#E69F00", "#56B4E9"),name="Early or late\nSeason",breaks=c("1","2"),labels=c("Early","Late"))
q2<-q+coord_fixed()+scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0))+scale_y_continuous((expand=c(0,0)))+xlim(0,.25)+ylim(0,.25)
```

[graph 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQ23s.png)

However, what I want to know add are ratios expressed as lines on the graph. I have five lines to add to the graph and I am not sure the best way to add them. One way I have added them is with geom_abline as follows:

```
q<-ggplot(data,aes(x=prot..,y=carb..,group=factor(early.or.late),color=factor(early.or.late))+geom_point(),size=4)+scale_color_manual(values=c("#E69F00", "#56B4E9"),name="Early or late\nSeason",breaks=c("1","2"),labels=c("Early","Late"))
q2<-q+geom_abline(aes(intercept=0,slope=2.10559),size=2,lty=1,colour="#E69F00",show.legend=TRUE)+
  geom_abline(aes(intercept=0,slope=2.278689),size=2,lty=3,colour="#E69F00")+
  geom_abline(aes(intercept=0,slope=1.43309),size=2,lty=5,colour="#56B4E9")+
  geom_abline(aes(intercept=0,slope=1.610966),size=2,lty=1,colour="#56B4E9")
q3<-q2+coord_fixed()+scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0))+scale_y_continuous((expand=c(0,0)))+xlim(0,.25)+ylim(0,.25)
```

which produces the following graph:
[graph with ratio lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJ5mW.png)

**What I am confused with now is that I do not know how to add a legend detailing what each line represents.**

Also, I cant seem to find a better way to attempt this graph besides abline. Would there be a better function to use in my situation?

Thanks!

Here is my data:

```
data<-structure(list(ï..Vial = c(36L, 31L, 37L, 39L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 
78L, 80L, 85L, 87L, 89L, 64L, 65L, 68L, 70L, 26L, 27L, 67L, 33L, 
82L, 88L, 66L, 72L, 40L, 41L, 84L, 28L, 30L, 38L, 76L), Experiment = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", 
"B"), class = "factor"), Location = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Coonamble", 
"Ivanhoe", "Trangie"), class = "factor"), Field = c(2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), Plot.Trans = c(2L, 
1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L), Transect = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), early.or.late = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), Functional.Group = structure(c(5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("", 
"fern", "forb", "frob", "grass", "Grass", "rushes", "sedge", 
"Sedge", "shrub"), class = "factor"), Species = structure(c(7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 8L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 28L, 28L, 23L, 23L, 34L, 31L, 31L, 32L, 
35L), .Label = c("Buffel cenchrus cillarnes", "Cannonball", "Chloris Truncata", 
"Danthonia caespitesa", "Diplachne fusca", "Dissocarpus caradoucus", 
"Enteropogon acirularis", "Eragrostis parviflora", "Gymnoschoenus sphaerocephalus", 
"Juncus", "Marsilea drummondii", "Medicago polymorpha", "Paspalidium constrictum", 
"Paspalidium jubiflorium", "Queana", "Sedge Spp.", "Sida Spp", 
"Solarium esuriah", "Stipa Bigeniculata", "Stipa Scailura", "Stipa Scarpra", 
"Stipa Scrbra", "Stipa spp", "Stipa Spp", "Stipa Spp.", "Stipa variable", 
"Stipa Variable", "Stipa Variables", "Tribulus terrestris", "Tribulus Terrestris", 
"Unknown C", "Unknown E", "Unknown Forb", "Unknown Grass", "Unknown Grass 3", 
"Unknown Herb A", "Unknown Herb B", "Walhalleya Subxerophila"
), class = "factor"), carb.. = c(0.129333365, 0.202844822, 0.142275002, 
0.236668235, 0.169526039, 0.115846616, 0.213292819, 0.113944998, 
0.124599354, 0.143516228, 0.115867745, 0.146299899, 0.102153528, 
0.158337108, 0.191291861, 0.215434765, 0.183662016, 0.095864692, 
0.179608436, 0.19113643, 0.234070371, 0.18278671, 0.186428087, 
0.194377919, 0.145811916, 0.17748817, 0.186150973, 0.144640378, 
0.170878979, 0.153140185, 0.145762334), prot.. = c(0.251963957, 
0.231460224, 0.205105442, 0.208611869, 0.260078976, 0.260470299, 
0.206310414, 0.142409299, 0.135318216, 0.088785988, 0.123123662, 
0.172596121, 0.109418993, 0.117703208, 0.132949015, 0.129416645, 
0.231538345, 0.21764968, 0.116498089, 0.173706485, 0.06157231, 
0.134473911, 0.095607729, 0.145505098, 0.1587147, 0.213428882, 
0.082957063, 0.253450972, 0.295918143, 0.300092067, 0.14219478
)), .Names = c("ï..Vial", "Experiment", "Location", "Field", 
"Plot.Trans", "Transect", "early.or.late", "Functional.Group", 
"Species", "carb..", "prot.."), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(36L, 
37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 53L, 54L, 
55L, 56L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 93L, 94L, 97L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 
106L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 111L))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a somewhat hacky solution. It works, but I had to change the point shape so that I could use the fill aesthetic to color the points and the color aesthetic for the lines - when I just used color for both of them, I needed to specify 6 color values, and ggplot put the lines and points in the same legend.

First, store the names, intercepts, and slopes in a data frame:

```
    ratios <- data.frame(intercept = rep(0, 4), 
                 slope = c(2.10559, 2.278689, 1.43309, 1.61066), 
                 Ratio = paste("ratio", 1:4))
```

Then, create all the lines with one call to `geom_abline`.

```
    ggplot(data, aes(x = prot.., y = carb.., group = factor(early.or.late), 
                     fill = factor(early.or.late))) +
       geom_point(size = 4, pch = 21) +
       scale_fill_manual(values = c("#E69F00", "#56B4E9"), name = "Season",
                         labels = c("Early","Late")) +
       scale_color_manual(values = rep(c("#E69F00", "#56B4E9"), 2)) +
       scale_linetype_manual(values = rep(c(1,3), each = 2)) +
       geom_abline(aes(intercept = intercept, slope = slope, color = Ratio, 
                       lty = Ratio), data = ratios, 
                   show.legend = TRUE, size = 2) + 
       scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0), limits = c(0, 0.25)) + 
       scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0), limits = c(0, 0.25)) +
       guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(color = NA))) +
       coord_fixed()
```

Here's the result:
[image: Here's the result]
I had to change the line types because some of the previous line types looked the same in the legend. I used `override.aes = list(color = NA)` because otherwise the legend for season has black lines going through it.

To change the names of the lines in the legend, just replace `paste("ratio", 1:4)` with the actual values you'd like to use.

**Edit:** use `stroke = NA` in the call to `geom_point` to get rid of the black border.